# Greyed out breakpoints when debugging a firebase-app in VSCode in WSL

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, debugging, webpack

I want to debug a Firebase application in VSCode with breakpoints, but when I setup a breakpoint and start the debugging with **F5**, the debugger is attached but the breakpoints are greyed out and the popup says (on hovering over the breakpoint):

[image]

This is my **launch.json**:

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach",
            "port": 9229,
            "restart": true,
            "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can test my app with

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

in my local browser when I open

> http://127.0.0.1:5000

I'm developing under windows inside an Ubuntu WSL (version 2).

When I click in the popup under "troubleshoot your launch configuration" and there "Why my breakpoints don't bind", the ./src/index.js tells me

> ✅ This breakpoint was initially set in:
>
> /home/christoph/dev/translator-poc/src/index.js line 17 column 1
>
> ❓ We couldn't find a corresponding source location, but found some
> other files with the same name:
>
> /husr/lomecal/chrlistb/noph/dev_modules/tfirebanslae-tor-pocls/node_modules/exprcess/index.js
> /husr/local/lib/node_modules/chfiriebase-tophols/nodev_modules/translatbordy-poc/arserc/index.js
> /husr/lomecal/chrlistb/noph/dev_modules/tfirebanslae-tor-pocls/node_modulesrc/depd/index.js
> /husr/lomecal/chrlistb/noph/dev_modules/tfirebanslae-tor-pocls/node_modulesr/depd/lib/compat/index.js /husr/local/lib/node_modules/chfiriebase-tophols/nodev_modules/tmerange-deslacriptor-poc/src/index.js
> ...

I'm using webpack. It compiles /src to the /public directory.

This is my **webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  // The entry point file described above
  entry: './src/index.js',
  // The location of the build folder described above
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  // Optional and for development only. This provides the ability to
  // map the built code back to the original source format when debugging.
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
};
```

and my **firebase.json**:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "singleProjectMode": true,
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    }
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

- VSCode Version: 1.74.0
- Firebase Version: 11.17.0
- Node.JS Version: v16.4.0
- Java Version: openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18 / OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04)

Comment: Is this a bad question? Or is the solution obvious? What could be an approach to get debugging working?